# Keras - Dense and Conv2D values

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Images that I would like to use to train the network are about the size of `4000px*3000px` and about `40k` of them, sorted in `250` classes.
I have made a CNN shown below:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((imgHeight, imgWidth, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding = 'same'), # filters, kernel_size
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(250),
])
```

How do I figure out what `layers.Conv2D(*16*, ...)`, a value I need?
How do I figure out what `layers.Dense(*250*)`, a value I need?

Because I can't start the training process, I'm running out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shape of the `Flatten()` layer is 96 Million, and so the final dense layer of your model has 24 Billion parameters, this is why you are running out of memory. There are some steps you can take to fix this issue:
Try resizing your images to a smaller shape, if `4000x3000x1` isn't necessary, 160x160x1 would be a good choice.
Try using more `Conv2D` layers followed by a `MaxPool2D` layer to decrease the size of the input, and then finally at the end, use a `Flatten` layer followed by a `Dense` layer.
For example:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((160, 160, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding = 'same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    layers.Flatten(),

    layers.Dense(512),
    layers.Dense(250),
])
```

This type of architecture will work well if you are doing a classification task, and will not run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can get it to start. What `batch_size` would you recommend, I've read that `32` or `64` is the best?

Comment: @Rukiits It actually depends on the size of your images and the limits of your GPU and memory

Comment: Used your model with image size `320, 320` and `batch_size = 32`. Went well for 6 epochs till suddenly loss went from `1-2` up to `52 000 000` and accuracy dropped from `0,70` to `0,50` and when a new epoch started accuracy was `0`. What could've caused this?

Comment: This may have happened due to something related to the optimizer, or loss function, or maybe your input data wasn't normalised, or something else, need to see the code.
Post this as another question, I'll answer it there.

Comment: Did that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072142/keras-losing-accuracy-and-loss-skyrocketing